# Insert rows in between every row matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, row

I have a 2920x640 matrix in matlab and I would like to transform this into a 8760x640 matrix by inserting 2 rows with zeros after every row.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

See duplicate answer since added. From this you'll need a small change to only affect rows, rather than rows *and* columns....

Create an array of all-zeros and then overwrite every third row with the original values:

```
A = rand(2920,640);                 % Your input array

B = zeros(size(A,1)*3, size(A,2));  % An array of all-zeros
B(1:3:end, :) = A;                  % Overwrite every third row with originals
```

Comment: I don't really see why changing `2` to `3` really necessitates a new answer.

Comment: In your [edit note](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49183953/2), you say beaker removed their comment. Just for your info; those "Possible duplicate" comments are automatically generated when a flag is raised, and automatically deleted when the question is fully marked as duplicate.